# "Температурознижувальний" замість "жарознижуючий"?

Tags: вживання-слів, калька, росіянізм

У випуску серії "Педагогіка" зустрілося, як приклад вислову, що є калькою російської мови з публіцистики «жарознижуючий» потрібно заміняти на «температурознижувальний». При чому "жарознижуючий" є в Тлумачному словнику. Та й в медичний літературі "температурознижувальний" радше виключення...

Comment: частина *знижувальний* мені подобається, бо це означає призначенний для зниження. Але тут, мабуть, цікавить саме перша частина, *жаро-* або *температуро-*.

Comment: Наші критерії якості вимагають, щоб запитання містило **контекст**. Знижувати жар або температуру може медикамент, а може корпус якої-небудь печі чи літального апарату, наприклад.
Також, якщо ви посилаєтеся на словники, то варто вказувати не назву, а URL. Будь ласка, перегляньте сторінки [tour], [ask] а також
[«Якими мають бути гарні запитання і відповіді»](http://meta.ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/5/). Щоб виправити запитання, натисніть [edit] у лівому нижньому куті під запитанням.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[СУМ-20](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=26761&page=901) подає словникову статтю щодо лексеми "жарознижувальний" (оскільки про "жарознижуючий" немає. Ймовірно, у зв’язку з тим, що українська мова оминає суфіксів -уч- / -юч- на кшталт *нотуючий - нотувальний*):

> **ЖАРОЗНИ́ЖУВАЛЬНИЙ**, а, е. Який знижує жар (у 3 знач.).
>
> Сполуки кремнію виявляють, особливо в гомеопатичних дозах, протизапальну, знеболювальну, жарознижувальну дію (з наук. літ.);
>
> Популярними потогінними та жарознижувальними засобами справедливо вважають липовий цвіт, квітки бузини чорної, плоди малини звичайної (з навч. літ.);
>
> // у знач. ім. жарозни́жувальне, ного, с. Засіб для зниження жару (у 3 знач.).
>
> Він знайшов жарознижувальне, та коли повернувся до вітальні зі склянкою води та пігулкою, то просто остовпів! (Люко Дашвар).

Примітки щодо використання (розмовне, застаріле, діалектизм) нема. Отже, цілком нормально використовувати це слово.

Аби точніше з’ясувати, звернімося до ще одної лексеми "жар" ([у цьому ж словнику](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=26741&page=900)) саме у третьому значенні, оскільки друга частинка "знижувальний" використовується з першою саме у третьому значенні:

> **ЖАР**, у, ч. 3. Підвищена температура тіла під час хвороби.
>
> Мені сьогодні легше, жару нема, і я навіть гуляв на балконі (М. Коцюбинський).

Як бачимо, теж позначення на обмежене використання слова нема.

Щодо іншого слова "температурознижувальний", то у цьому словнику його ще нема, оскільки наразі вийшли томи 1-8. Також інформації не знайшла ні в "СУМ-11", ні у словнику за ред. Б. Грінченка, ні на сайті "Оnline corrector", ні на Офіційному сайті Української мови.

Отож, слово "жарознижувальний" хоч і з першого погляду нагадує русизм, однак є цілком нормативним в українській мові.

P. S.: Крім того, знаю, що навіть у діалектах є слово "жар" у значенні "температура" і як трохи віддалене від нього "жарівка", що означає лампочка. Чому наводжу саме ці слова, бо тут однаковий корінь жар-. Також і тут, і тут йдеться про виділення теплоти. Можливо, це й етимологічно споріднені слова. А це ще раз підтверджує, що слово "жарознижувальний" не є русизмом.